# Dependencies в Maven

Tags: java, maven

Вопрос, возможно, глупый, но я так и не нашел на эту тему ничего понятного в гугле.Собственно для чего нужны dependencies в maven.На сколько я понял это просто более удобно реализованный импорт?Прав ли я?(+ имеют ли они что то общее с di?)

Comment: На Ваш вопрос вы сами ответите как только попробуете создать проект maven с возможность преобразования класса в JSON через GSON.

Comment: Есть разные библиотеки. Их очень много, держать все на своем ПК нет смысла и это нецелесообразно. Maven позволяет подключить любую необходимую для проекта библиотеку, которая содержится у него в репозитории. А разработчик не тратит время на посещение сайта, где эту библиотеку можно скачать, скачивание ее, не ищет самостоятельно место, куда нужно ее положить и так далее. Все за него делает Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую описать для чего нужны такие системы сборки как **gradle, maven, sbt** и прочее.
Они имеют несколько задач:

1. **Стандартизировать процесс сборки** проекта. Вам не нужно думать о том, как запускать тесты (с какими параметрами, в какой очередности), не нужно знать о том, под какой версией java собирать, какую использовать кодировку и пр.
2. **Управление зависимостями**. Больше не нужно в ручную скачивать из интернета нужную версию библиотеки. Система сборки это сделает за вас - сама сходит в нужный репозиторий, найдет и загрузит все что нужно.
3. **Легкая кастомизация**. Как правило, такие системы используют плагины, скрипты и пр. которые могут быть легко добавлены в определенные этапы сборки. Это позволяет опять же стандартизировать процесс, а так же без проблем для конечного пользователя расширять функциональность.

Answer (score 0):

Очень помогает при разработке проекта. Для подключения сотрудника в проект достаточно скинуть ему проект, после чего maven подтянет нужные версии библиотек(зависимости). Так же исключает возможность разработку одного с использование разных версий библиотек.